# how to add Functors with generic types on the function?

Tags: rust

The title is probably confusing, but I am not sure how to express this idea very well. I will clarify what I mean.
Is it possible to pass a function that acts differently depending on the variable passed to it.
Let me give you this example

```rust
trait Lift<A, B> {
    type Source;
    type Target1;
}
impl<A, B> Lift<A, B> for Option<A> {
    type Source = Self;
    type Target1 = Option<B>;
}
trait Functor<A, B>: Lift<A, B> {
    fn fmap<F>(self, f: F) -> <Self as Lift<A, B>>::Target1
    where
        F: Fn(A) -> B;
}
impl<A, B> Functor<A, B> for Option<A> {
    fn fmap<F>(self, f: F) -> <Self as Lift<A, B>>::Target1
    where
        F: Fn(A) -> B,
    {
        self.map(f)
    }
}
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
struct Identity<T>(T);
impl<A, B> Lift<A, B> for Identity<A> {
    type Source = Self;
    type Target1 = Identity<B>;
}
impl<A, B> Functor<A, B> for Identity<A> {
    fn fmap<F>(self, f: F) -> <Self as Lift<A, B>>::Target1
    where
        F: Fn(A) -> B,
    {
        Identity(f(self.0))
    }
}
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
struct Pair<T>(T,T);
impl<A, B> Lift<A, B> for Pair<A> {
    type Source = Self;
    type Target1 = Pair<B>;
}
impl<A, B> Functor<A, B> for Pair<A> {
    fn fmap<F>(self, f: F) -> <Self as Lift<A, B>>::Target1
    where
        F: Fn(A) -> B,
    {
        Pair(f(self.0),f(self.1))
    }
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
struct Pair2<T,E>(T,E);
impl<A,D, B,C> Lift<(A,C), (B,D)> for Pair2<A,C> {
    type Source = Self;
    type Target1 = Pair2<B,D>;
}
//Can you even implement a functor that takes a generic function?
impl<A, B,C,D> Functor<(A,C), (B,D)> for Pair2<A,C> {
    fn fmap<F>(self, f: F) -> <Self as Lift<(A,C),  (B,D)>>::Target1
    where
        F: Fn((A,C)) -> (B,D),
    {
        let a=f((self.0,self.1));
        Pair2(a.0,a.1)
    }
}


fn main() {
    let a=Some(5);
    println!("{:?}\n{:?}",a,a.fmap(|a| a+2));
    let a=Identity(5);
    println!("{:?}\n{:?}",a,a.fmap(|a| a+2));
    let a=Pair(4,7);
    println!("{:?}\n{:?}",a,a.fmap(|a| a+2));
    let a=Pair2(4,6.8);
    //challenge, make a fmap that takes a variadic a and adds 2 or something like that like in just "Pair"
    println!("{:?}\n{:?}",a,a.fmap(|a| (a.0+2,a.1+3.4)));
    
}
```

https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/90nk7p
This is the output

```
Some(5)
Some(7)
Identity(5)
Identity(7)
Pair(4, 7)
Pair(6, 9)
Pair2(4, 6.8)
Pair2(6, 10.2)
```

Ok that's pretty cool, what I would like to do, is to create an fmap on Pair2 such that it "works" exactly like the one above just Pair, coercing the types. Is there a way to do this?
What I mean, instead of a function that takes a tuple, I can give a function that takes a single element, that changes depending on the type.
That is to say

```rust
fn id<T>(a: T) -> T {
        a
    }
let a=Pair2(4,6.8);
a.fmap(id)
//This would somehow work.
```

Or for example

```rust
a.fmap(Some)
//This would wrap it into
//Pair2(Some(4),Some(6.8))
```

Comment: Could you add an example of the code you'd like to be able to write?

Comment: The best way to achieve this would be higher-kinded types, which are not yet part of Rust. However, Generic Associated Types were [recently stabilized](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/10/28/gats-stabilization.html), which might help in achieving your goal.

Answer (score 0):

With functions, no. Type parameters are early bound, meaning that `Some` is always `Some::<T>` with *some* `T`, it can be multiple `T`s.

You may be able to go with a custom generic trait, but I don't see how given that the bounds on `Functor::fmap()` are dictated by the trait.